# Noir camera not disengaging when program closed

Tags: python, camera

I am using a python script to access my NoIr Pi camera module via the "picamera" package.
Yesterday everything was working fine.

Today everything is *still* working fine, however whenever I close my python scrpit, the red LED stays on, and it appears that the pi is still trying to use the camera.

When run my script again, it is unable to access the camera due to lack of resources (I.e the previous closed script still has access to the camera)

After a quick reboot I can run my script again, but its getting a little tedious having to reboot every time I make a change when trying to debug my script.

Any idea's?

**Update - Code as requested**

```
fwidth  = (351) // 32 * 32
fheight = (255) // 16 * 16

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    with picamera.array.PiYUVArray(camera) as stream:
        stream = open('image.data', 'w+b')
        camera.resolution = (320, 240)
        time.sleep(2)

        fcntl.fcntl(comm, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)

        while True:                
            camera.capture(stream, format='yuv', use_video_port = True)
            stream.seek(0)

            image = np.fromfile(stream, dtype=np.uint8, count=fwidth*fheight).reshape((fheight, fwidth))
```

Comment: can we see the code?

Comment: Sure, hang on i'll post the relevant part here.

Comment: BTW... 32*32 != 351 and 16*16 != 255

Comment: I know ;) "//" is a floor division symbol (not comments) to make sure only the luminescence value was pulled from the YUV input (wanted it to be as fast as possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the stream. The object you named `stream` *is a* `ByteIO`, that in turn is-a [`IOBase`](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/io.html#io.IOBase). It should be closed to ensure proper release and clean-up. You need a condition in your loop, and when that turns to false, you need to do a graceful exit involving `stream.close()`

Comment: I actually truncate the stream instead at the bottom of my loop as its constantly in use. (I didn't post the whole loop as its massive) The stream should be closing even without that line if I close the terminal that the script is running in.

I don't think the error is with the code, as it was working fine yesterday and I have made no changes, I think it might be something to do with power perhaps?

Comment: I tried adding the stream.close() as you suggested, it threw an exception when I ran it, so I removed it again.

And now strangely my bug has gone! I guessed a force close from the exception must have made a change to something that persists through a reboot.

So looks like your suggestion fixed it even if it wasn't in the way you thought :) Cheers.

Comment: I should point out that if you're using PiYUVArray, you can access `stream.array` to get a numpy array of the image without messing around with things like `np.fromfile` and reshaping; the PiYUVArray class does all that for you.

Comment: Cheers Dave, I will take a look at it. Great lib thanks for making!